# JQGrid Horizontal srollbar not working

Tags: jqgrid

Experts,
I need horizontal scrollbar in my JQgrid. The scrollbar is visible but it does not work as the columns are getting wrapped. I do not want wrapping and allow user to scroll horizontally. I tried everything found on google but in vain. Going forward the number of columns would increase. Please help.

```
    $("#test1").jqGrid({
    url: hostPath + '/test/test',
    postData: {
        modelDataRequest: window.ModelPart
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Post',
    height: 'auto',
    colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2','col3','col4','col5', 'col6', 'col7','col8', 'col9', 'col10', 'col11', 'col12'],
    colModel: [
  {name: 'col1', index: 'col1', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col2', index: 'col2', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col3', index: 'col3', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col4', index: 'col4', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col5', index: 'col5', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col6', index: 'col6', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col7', index: 'col7', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col8', index: 'col8', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col9', index: 'col9', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col10', index: 'col10', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col11', index: 'col11', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},
  {name: 'col12', index: 'col12', width: '150px', search: true, align: 'left'},

    ],
        gridview: true,
        loadOnce: true,
        sortable: true,
        shrinkToFit: false, 
        //search: true,
        pager: '#Pager',
        jsonReader: { cell: "" },
        rowNum: 50,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100, 500, 1000],
        viewrecords: true,
        emptyrecords: 'No record(s) to display',
        caption: "Search Results",
        altRows: true,
        altclass: 'jqGridAltRow',
        loadComplete: function () {
            if ($(this).getGridParam("records") == 0) {
                $(this).parents('div.ui-jqgrid-div').css("max-height", "0px");
                $(this).html("<div style='padding:6px;background:#D8D8D8'>No records found</div>");
            }
            else {
                $(this).parents('div.ui-jqgrid-div').css("max-height", "450px");

        }
        $(this).parents('div.ui-jqgrid-div').css("max-width", "100%");
    },
    gridComplete: function () {
        $('#recordsCount').text($('#test1').getGridParam('records'));           

    },

},

{
    closeOnEscape: true, closeAfterSearch: true, ignoreCase: true, multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, showQuery: true,
    sopt: ['cn', 'eq'],
    defaultSearch: 'cn'
})
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <=4.7? Can you please post the server response - i.e the data commong from the server or better you can prepare a example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hi Tony, I am using JQgrid 4.6. I have not used jsfiddle before, however I would try to create one. the problem is the scroll is not working and it is shrinking the header to fit in the defined width.